# Java Actions Clarification

Tags: java

So, typically, I'm a C, C++, and C# programmer, with most of my GUI experience in C# WPF.  I've been placed on a project that uses Java and I'm finding my vocabulary for C# doesn't mix well with Java.

One issue I've come across deals with JButtons, and presumably anything that has what is known as 'delegates' in C#.  From this [example](http://www.javabeginner.com/java-swing/java-jbutton-class-example) there's this bit of code:

```
jbnButton1.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    {
        jtfInput.setText("Button 1!");
    }
});
```

Simply, what is this called, where a function is defined as a parameter(or passed as a parameter)?  Also, is this a best practice?  In the project I'm on, the Initialize() function is filled with functions like this for buttons, check boxes, etc, which makes it a rather un-wieldy function.  I'd much prefer having the definition at the class level, instead of within Initialize().

Which brings me to another [example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html)(the top code example).  With these lines of code:

```
    b1.addActionListener(this);
    b3.addActionListener(this);
...
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if ("disable".equals(e.getActionCommand())) {
        b2.setEnabled(false);
        b1.setEnabled(false);
        b3.setEnabled(true);
    } else {
        b2.setEnabled(true);
        b1.setEnabled(true);
        b3.setEnabled(false);
    }
}
```

Essentially, the code assigns the action for button one, b1, and button three, b3 to the same event handler, which is defined at the scope I prefer(outside of where the buttons are being initialized).  Is there a way to make them point to different functions?  Also, by calling

```
.addActionListener(this);
```

How does the compiler figure out to use actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) in this?  Is something pre-defined that says actions will resolve to 'actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)'?

Comment: for your second question: this is the current class, which must implement the ActionListener interface. The compiler does not "figure out" to use actionPerformed. Instead, the addActionListener requires that the parameter implement the ActionListener interface, which includes the actionPerformed() method.  Use ActionEvent.getSource() to determine if b1 or b3 was clicked then call the appropriate method from the actionPerformed method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first example is called an *Anonymous Class*. It is often used for listeners (like `ActionListener`s), but should only be used if you never have to remove the listener since there is no reference being saved.

For the second part of the question, the compiler does not figure out when to call `actionPerformed`. It is declared in the `ActionListener` [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html):

> When the action event occurs, that object's actionPerformed method is invoked.

Thus, it is the `JButton`'s responsibility to call `actionPerformed` on all `ActionListener`s that have been added to it whenever an action occurs.

There is no way to make `b1` and `b3` point to different methods. This is a good example of where an anonymous class would make for a better design:

```
b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        b2.setEnabled(false);
        b1.setEnabled(false);
        b3.setEnabled(true);
    }
});

b3.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        b2.setEnabled(true);
        b1.setEnabled(true);
        b3.setEnabled(false);
    }
});
```

Assuming `b1` has the lable "disable". Then `this` would no longer have to implement `ActionListener`.

Answer (score 1):

The first example you give is called an "anonymous inner class".  You are defining an anonymous sub-class of `ActionListener`, overriding its `actionPerformed` method, instantiating it (creating an instance of this subclass) and then passing a reference to that instance to the method `jbnButton1.addActionListener`.  This is the closest Java comes to having "closures" for now (at least until Java 8).

This is idiomatic when the action listener is simple, but you could recode this as

```
class MyListener extends ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    {
        jtfInput.setText("Button 1!");
    }
}
...
jbnButton1.addActionListener(new MyListener());
```

but then you might have to arrange a constructor for `MyListener` to accept and save the `jtfInput` reference.  The inline definition simplifies this. But for a more complex situation you may well want to define the class out-of-line.

As to the second question:

```
.addActionListener(this);
```

The class in which this appears must implement the `ActionListener` interface, so it must have an `actionPerformed()` method.  That is what lets the framework "know" what to invoke.

Answer (score 1):

For your second code example:

It knows to use that `actionperformed()` because the class you are using to add the `actionlistener`-s to buttons is implementing the interface `ActionListener`

and if you pass to `addActionListener` method your own class (this) where you must implement `actionPerformed` method, it works just as the `anonymous classes`, because it's an `ActionListener`

The `addActionListener` method knows it has an `actionPerformed` method (it must have one), so it will automatically call that